Not able to upload packages and edit pages after moving AEM instance from centOS to Rocky Linux
We need to migrate an AEM 6.5.9 instance from a centOS7 to a Rocky Linux 9 server. Our initial idea was to just copy over the whole instance via rsync from the centOS to the Rocky Linux server using the steps described here: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/experience-cloud-kcs/kbarticles/ka-16875.
The process itself is working fine, all permissions, file owners and timestamps seem to be unchanged, as far as we can tell. Also, the instance is starting up fine. However, there are multiple issues with the new instance:

When we are trying to upload a package via crx/packmgr, we either get an "package file parameter missing" or an "No such file or directory" error. We've tested this with multiple packages, all of them are showing the same errors. Uploading the same packages on the centOS AEM instance is working fine.
When opening an existing page in either Classic or Touch UI for editing, the page itself is rendering fine. But we can not add / edit / delete any components, as no elements for editing are rendering.
No messages are shown in error log when performing such actions.
Creating new pages and editing components on these new pages is working fine.
Editing existing OSGi configurations via /system/console/configMgr is also working fine.

We are using the same Java Version 1.8.0_161 on both servers. SELinux is also deactivated on both servers.
We've copied the instance multiple times to make sure the issue is not caused by anything happening during the process. But we've seen the same results every time.
Consistency check on the repo via oak-run did not find any issues.
Does anyone have any hints on what could be wrong or what we should check to get the instance running on Rocky Linux?

How do you copy it? using scp, cp -a, rsync? I usually prefer to do a full offline copy, if some downtime is allowed.

Hi @ronnyfm, we are using rsync. However, as the deadline came closer and we did not have a viable solution, we decided to set up the instances from scratch

I can't tell what the problem might be, but I can suggest some steps to diagnose it.

Try installing a brand new instance on the Rocky Linux 9 and see if it shows the same issues or if it allows package installs just fine. This will tell you whether it's the operating system being incompatible with the basic AEM 6.5.9 instance. The easiest install is just dropping the main jar file into a directory and running it; it does its own whole installation thing.

If the installation from 1. works fine, then it's something with the copying process. Check any configurations rsync is copying to see if they have any values in them that mean different things between the different Linux versions.  Or try and see if you can migrate your content and code packages to the working instance.
If the installation from 1. has the same issue, open a ticket with Adobe asking about running on Rocky Linux 9. They might have a patch of some kind available. It might even work with your rsync'd instance.
